# Why is A(B ∩ C) ≠ AB ∩ AC?

Tags: sets

I am told A(B ∩ C) ≠ AB ∩ AC
I am unsure as to why they are not equal. Using examples and following them I am unable to show that they are not.

e.g Let A = {m} B = {s, p} C = {p, r}

A(B ∩ C) = A{p} = {mp}

AB ∩ AC = {ms, mp} ∩ {mp, mr} = {mp}

Have I made a mistake here?

Comment: Is this a counterexample? A={m,mm,n,nn}, B={m}, C={n}.

Comment: Can you explain your notation of AB? Is it concatenation (as in formal langauges), or some other set operation? Also, in general it helps to start extremely simple when looking for counter-examples.

Comment: See [Why is string concatenation not distributive over intersection?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70174/4287), or earlier   [Concatenation of the intersection of two languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16334/concatenation-of-the-intersection-of-two-languages),